# Filter pd.DataFrame rows by list of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to select rows where value in one of the columns is not equal to 0. Here is the code:

```
tmp = train[(train['col1'] > 0) | (train['col2'] > 0) |
        (train['col3'] > 0) | (train['col4'] > 0) |
        (train['col5'] > 0)]
```

How can I accomplish the same result by iterating over the list of columns, e.g. ['col1', 'col2', ..., 'col5']?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#use .any to check if any of the elements in a row is greater than 0.
train = train[(train>0).any()]

#if only need to check certain columns, this should work.
train[(train[['col1', 'col2', ..., ]]>0).max(1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain what does `max(1)` mean? I thought it's amount of columns which should meet the condition, but seems like that's not the case.

Comment: `train[(train[['col1', 'col2', ..., ]]>0).any(axis=1)]` would also work.

Comment: max(1) means to find the max value on each row. Because True > False so if there is any True in the row, the max will be True which will cause the row to be selected.